# nonatomic append failure outcomes

Tags: ios

I've got a file that I want to append to. It's pretty important to me that this is both fast (I'm calling it 50hz on an iPhone 4) and safe.

I've looked at atomic appending. It seems to me like I would have to copy the whole file, append to it, and then use the NSFileManager's `replaceItemAtURL` to move them over, which sounds rather slow.

On the other hand, I could simply suck up a non-atomic append, *assuming* that the failure conditions are strictly that some subset of bytes at the *end* of the data I'm trying to write are not written. My file format writes out the length of each chunk first, so if there's not enough space for the length data or the length data is bigger than the available bytes, I can detect a partial write and discard.

The question is, how feasible would it be to use an atomic append to rapidly atomically append small amounts of data (half a kilobyte or so at a time), and what exactly are the failure outcomes of a non-atomic append?

Edit: I am the only one appending to this file. I am concerned only with external failure conditions, e.g. process termination, device running out of power, disk full, etc. I am currently using a synchronous append.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on what kind of atomicity you need? Are you protecting against synchronous appends (from multiple threads or processes)? Do you also want to prevent non-cooperative synchronous file events (like a backup daemon or so)? Or do you want to make sure appends are atomic in regards to (abnormal) process termination?

Comment: I'm the only appendee and mostly concerned with events like process termination,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIX gives no guarantees about atomicity of `write(2)` when writing to a file.

If the platform does not provide any other means of writing that grants additional characteristics (and I'm not aware of any such API in iOS) you basically have to live with the possibility that the write could be partial.

The workaround of many Cocoa APIs (like `-[NSData writeToFile:atomically:]`) is the mechanism you mentioned: Perform the work on a temporary file and then atomically `link(2)` the new over the old file. This strategy does not apply well to your use case as it requires a copy of the old contents.

I would suggest the non-atomic approach you already considered. Actually I once used a very similar mechanism in an iOS app where I had to write a transcript of user actions for crash recovery. The recovery code thoroughly tested the transcript for integrity and would bail out on unexpected errors. Yet, I never received a single report of a corrupt file.

Comment: Right, but the question is, what *is* a partial write, exactly? For some partial write situations I just don't care; the question is how bad that situation actually is.

Comment: I think there's no official definition of what *can* happen—at least POSIX does not grant one. I'd go for a mixture of common sense and testing. I suppose any interrupted `write` could write any number of bytes (zero to all), but always in the original order and without gaps. But that's just my assumption.